# WordPress - How to get 1 latest post of 5 categories so the total post will be 5 Posts

Tags: wordpress

I have this variable with 5 categories:

```
 $category_needed = implode( ', ', $category_needed );
```

Output is:

```
arts-entertainment, learning, news, real-estate, uncategorized
```

Now, I want to get only the 1 latest post of the above categories.

So the total posts will be 5 **FROM** the  5 latest post of 5 categories.

**To do that my code is below:**

```
   $category_needed = implode( ', ', $category_needed );
    $post_args = [
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'numberposts' => 5,
        'category' => [ $category_needed ]
    ];
```

But I see I have 2 posts of **same** category which I don't want.

Is there any work arount?

**Update:**

```
echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $category_needed );
echo '</pre>';
```

## Return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 1
)

$latest_posts = array();

foreach ( $category_needed as $cat_id ){  // $category_ids is array of category ids
    $post_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'category' => $cat_id,
    );
    $latest_post_of_category = get_posts( $post_args );
    $latest_posts[] = $latest_post_of_category[0];
}

foreach ( $latest_posts as $latest_post ) {
    $cat = get_the_category( $latest_post->ID);
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $cat[0]->name );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

**Now, it returns:**

Arts & Entertainment
Learning
Learning
Real Estate
Real Estate

It's should be unique category, right?

Comment: try with `'cat' => '2,6,17,38'`. pass the categories Id in the value.

Comment: Not working.. same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to get only 1 post from every categories.

You need to get latest post in each categories within foreach block of category.

```
$latest_posts = array();
$exclude_post_ids = array(); // Added
foreach ( $category_ids as $cat_id ){  // $category_ids is array of category ids
    $post_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'category' => $cat_id,
        'exclude' => $exclude_post_ids, // Added
    );
    $latest_post_of_category = get_posts( $post_args );
    $latest_posts[] = $latest_post_of_category[0];
    $exclude_post_ids[] = $latest_post_of_category[0]->ID; // Added

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r( get_cat_name( $cat_id ) . $latest_post_of_category[0]->post_title );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

I added some code.
Because post can be associated to multiple categories, so you need to check the post is already obtained.

Comment: Let me try with this

Comment: Please remember, 'category' variable of args should be id.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you check, please?

Comment: If post1 has "Arts & Entertainment" category, and post2 has "Arts & Entertainment" and "Learning" categories, your result can show duplicated category names.

Comment: There are no duplication category on each post. I have checked the updated code but still no luck

Comment: Please try updated code to check it. Print category name and obtained post title in loop. Are you sure each post doesn't have multiple categories? If it has multiple categories, your code for checking categories is not exact.

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: Perfectly, working for me :) Thanks a lot man. what were the issues?

Comment: Because Post can have multiple categories, though it was obtained from category2, if it has category1 and category2, category1 can be displayed with your code ( because you printed the first category only ), If my code works correctly, please set correct answer. :)